# Directive in pop up window angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popupwindow

I've a simple single page application. I want to implement tear off windows like functionality, like if I've a directive with a button in the tool bar that when clicked hides the directive in the main app, opens a pop up window (not a modal) and opens that directive in the popup window. Similarly when the button is clicked in the popup window it closes the popup window and the directive reappears in the main app.

Is it even possible? If so can you please provide me with some pointers?. so far I've looked into 
https://github.com/bulkan/angular-popup

Couldn't even get the thing running :(

Any help would be highly appreciated ..

Cheers

Comment: Hi pixelbits like I said I'm not looking for any overlays or modals I want it to be a stand alone pop up window

Comment: New window means new scope/application, so you'd have to find a clever way to implement some external storage combined with $watch to make something like that.

Comment: `window.postMessage()` can be used for communicating between the two windows. But as Shomz mentioned, keeping data in sync between the two instances will be an issue.

Comment: what @Shomz said. A new window will mean a completely new execution context